# Assigning Random Tags in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

When I run the following code, the debugger logs the values of all the tags as zero. Does anyone know why?

```
int placeHolderRandom = arc4random() % 13; 

self.cardOne.tag = 5; 

placeHolderRandom = arc4random() % 13; 

self.cardTwo.tag = placeHolderRandom; 

placeHolderRandom = arc4random() % 13; 

self.cardThree.tag = placeHolderRandom; 

placeHolderRandom = arc4random() % 13; 

self.cardFour.tag = placeHolderRandom; 

NSLog(@"%d , %d , %d , %d" , self.cardOne.tag , self.cardTwo.tag , self.cardThree.tag , self.cardFour.tag);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to be because `self.cardOne` and your other properties are `nil`.

Comment: No. They're instantiated in xcode, as UIButtons. Do I have to manually allocate and initialize them?

Comment: You've logged them and checked that they are not `nil`?  How are you instantiating them at the moment?  From a nib?  Have you checked that your outlets are connected up?

Comment: "They're instantiated in Xcode" is meaningless. Xcode is an IDE. Do you mean "instantiated in your XIB"?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. That was a typo. I meant in interface builder, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if your properties are instantiated. What matters is, did you connect the outlets correctly? The most common cause of code that should work, but doesn't, is outlets that are not connected. Check to see if those outlet properties are nil or not. I'm betting that they are nil.